# Alert before deleting UITableView cell - (UIAlertController) Swift or Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, uitableview, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I want to delete a Table View cell, but before that action happens I want to give the user an alertview. I got this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning"
                                                        message:@"Are you sure?"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"NO"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
        [alert show];

        [self.array removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//or something similar to this based on your data source array structure
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"Nee"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Nothing to do here");
    }
    else if([title isEqualToString:@"Ja"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Delete the cell");

    }
}
```

But now when I swipe to right on the cell and the delete button appears I got no AlertView. I only get the AlertView when I press on the delete button. When I press on the delete button the message appears but the cell is already been deleted.

How to make this work? So there is an AlertView when I swipe.

Comment: Don't tag stuff with "Xcode" if it's unrelated to Xcode.

Comment: @H2CO3: How often do you write that every day? (Just kidding.)

Comment: @MartinR Almost always when needed :P

Comment: @MartinR Can't tell you how many thousands of questions I've seen tagged `xcode` when the question has nothing to do with the IDE.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Regarding the sequence, everything is fine. `commitEditingStyle` will be called only when the delete button was pressed already. The point is that you are actually removing the object before the alert is responded to. Change it to this:

Add this to the .m file before `@implementation`:

```
@interface PutYourViewControllerClassNameHere
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *indexPathToBeDeleted;
@end
```

And then:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        self.indexPathToBeDeleted = indexPath;

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning"
                                                        message:@"Are you sure?"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"NO"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
        [alert show];
        // do not delete it here. So far the alter has not even been shown yet. It will not been shown to the user before this current method is finished.     
    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // This method is invoked in response to the user's action. The altert view is about to disappear (or has been disappeard already - I am not sure) 

    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"NO"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Nothing to do here");
    }
    else if([title isEqualToString:@"YES"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Delete the cell");

        [self.array removeObjectAtIndex:[self.indexPathToBeDeleted row]];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:self.indexPathToBeDeleted] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Edit: This should compile, despite minor syntax errors probably. 
General assupmtion: You are dealing with one section only. At least only with one section within deletions are possible.

Comment: You could use (abuse?) the `tag` property of `UIView` to pass the selected row to the alert delegate: `alert.tag = indexPath.row`.

Comment: After that code I got the following errors in - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex: Use of undeclared identifier 'indexPath'; did you mean 'NSIndexPath'? and Unknown receiver 'tableView'; did you mean 'UITableView'?

Comment: @MartinR, nice idea that with the (ab-)use of the tag.

Comment: @user1883396 that is exactly what I meant by saying that the code will not compile. `indexPath` ist not within the scope of clickedButtonAtIndex:. Wait a minute. I'll check the docs for you and get back with a working/compiling edit of my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked one more appearance of `indexPath`. See the new edit.

Comment: @HermannKlecker After your edit I got this error in the log: 2013-01-12 22:16:29.421 Myappname[4703:c07] Nothing to do here
2013-01-12 22:16:32.177 Myappname[4703:c07] Delete the cell
2013-01-12 22:16:32.179 Myappname[4703:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]' We are almost there. The NO button works only the YES button gives this error.

Comment: @HermannKlecker We are almost there. The NO button works only the YES button gives above error.

Comment: Frankly, I am not sure. First try NSLog (@"indexPath: %@",[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]); And add some NSLog to figure out where exactly it is thrown. (Better: Set an exception breakpoint to see where exactly the exception is thrown).

Comment: @HermannKlecker When I try NSLog (@"indexPath: %@",[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]); I got this: indexPath: (null) That means there is no indexPath right?

Comment: Yes.That means that no cell is selected at that point in time. That means that my suggestion did not work. Sorry for that. I'll use an ivar instead and edit the answer again in some minutes.

Comment: @HermannKlecker alright I will wait! Curious what the code would be!

Comment: We do remote-programming here :) Sorry that I did not have an exactly matching code sniplet ready. I made that slightly diffrerently in conjunction with core data objects. But I too added this UIAlert once. However, now it should work at least.

Comment: @HermannKlecker Works like a Charm! Thank you for your time and code! Give you a +1 now!

Answer (score 5):

### iOS 8 +

iOS 8 introduced `UIAlertController`. This allows you to write your delete and cancel code in completion blocks instead of in delegate methods (as per `-clickedButtonAtIndex` of the old `UIAlertView`).

**Swift 3**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "Are you sure?", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive, handler: { (action) in
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        })
        alertController.addAction(deleteAction)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Are you sure?" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction *deleteAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Delete" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }];
        [alertController addAction:deleteAction];

        UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
            NSLog(@"Don't do anything");
        }];
        [alertController addAction:cancelAction];

        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Youre calling the Alert when the deleting action is already taking place....

Put it in:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Waarschuwing!"
                                                message:@"Weet je zeker dat je het vak: lalaal wilt verwijderen?"
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Nee"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Ja", nil];
[alert show];
}
```

That will call the alert when the cell is swiped and before the button is pressed.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Now the UIAlertview needs to be fixed. What should I put in the - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{ ???

Comment: This delegate method is used to handle events of tap buttons: "Nee", "Ja", name it...
It's a good way to handle this with switch(buttonIndex). In case of 1(because "Ja" button is second) just delete the cell.

Answer (score 0):

**iOS 9.0 and Swift 2.3**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .Delete {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Warning!", message: "You're about to delete this stuff right meow.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let delete = UIAlertAction(title: "Do it.", style: .Destructive, handler: { action in

            tableView.beginUpdates()
            //delete from your datasource!
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            tableView.endUpdates()
        })

        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: { action in

            //this is optional, it makes the delete button go away on the cell
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        })

        alertController.addAction(delete)
        alertController.addAction(cancel)
        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```